# ListView in an activity with scrollable tabs

Tags: java, android, listview, tabs, scrollable

i'm doing an application which has an activity with "Scrollable tabs + swipe" navigation mode.
I want to put a ListView in this activity that change for every tab. Can I do that, or there are some kind of problems?

Here is my simple code:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class VisualMaterie extends FragmentActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visual_materie);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    // Acquisisce intent da altra activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.visual_materie, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 8 total pages.
        return 8;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_italiano).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_storia).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_inglese).toUpperCase(l);
        case 3:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_matematica).toUpperCase(l);
        case 4:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_informatica).toUpperCase(l);
        case 5:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_sistemie_reti).toUpperCase(l);
        case 6:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_tecnologie).toUpperCase(l);
        case 7:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_telecomunicazioni).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_visual_materie_dummy, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Hope to receive answers soon :)

Comment: Are you talking about same behaviour as PlayStore app? If yes, you have to use ViewPager and you can make your tap tabs scrollable.

Comment: Yes I did that, my problem is that I cannot put a ListView into those scrollable tabs. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for that page, but it's not what I'm looking for.

I have ALREADY done the activity with the ViewPager indicator, I wanna put a ListView in it. How can I do this?

Comment: You can extend your class with ListActivity instead of Activity rest all methods will be same.